# Suitable NXP card for MUSCLE applet

Tags: applet, javacard

I'm checking JCOP product range for a suitable version for MUSCLE applet.

CAP file size of this applet is 14KB.

which versions can be used for this applet?

http://www.nxp.com/documents/line_card/75016728.pdf

what parameter I should check for it? EEPROM or ROM?

Comment: Just a sidenote: do NOT use Muscle unless you know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly off topic, and it's probably not such a good idea to refer to a specific product as products are removed and added in time.

There is the `.cap` file size but note that the installed applet will take a bit less. You should however consider that `.cap` file size does not take memory required for installation and personalization in account.

You obviously need the asymmetric co-processor but you may not need contactless, so check for that.

Unless you want to pay for creating a [ROM mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_ROM) you should be looking at EEPROM or Flash (where available).

I'll quote Wikipedia:

> However, the one-time masking cost is high and there is a long turn-around time from design to product phase. Design errors are costly: if an error in the data or code is found, the mask ROM is useless and must be replaced in order to change the code or data.

Start thinking ROM after you've sold a few hundreds of thousands :)